# MySQL Syntax Query for Combining columns in one

Tags: mysql

Please. Help me. How to combine records of multiple columns in one new column ?
In my table I have 3 columns named PIO1, PIO2 and PIO3. So I want to combine the records of all three columns in one column.

This is my Column  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOnH4.png
and this is the output what I want to show  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKUmB.png

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected output since there are many possibilities to the question without having sample and expected data.

Comment: Use `SELECT CONCAT(PO1, PO2, PO3)` or something along these lines.

Comment: the output you showed has only one column value, but you told you want to combine the three column values

Comment: Yes. I want to combine but not the concatenation. I want it in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
alter table <tablename> add combocolumn varchar(3000);

update <tablename> set combocolumn = concat (PO1,PO2,PO3);
```

This assumes that "combine" means concatenate without adding a separator, and that 3000 characters will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you need records of all columns in same column, use UNION ALL

```
SELECT PIO FROM
(
    SELECT id as 'id', PIO1 as 'PIO' FROM tbl_name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id as 'id', PIO2 as 'PIO' FROM tbl_name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id as 'id', PIO3 as 'PIO' FROM tbl_name
) a 
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Thank you Sir..I will try it now

Comment: Sir I have a last question.

Comment: for counting the same values in one column, and display that value together with the total counts.

Comment: `SELECT PIO1, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_name GROUP BY 1` use same logic for other columns